# Can I use Rank with a non-continuous reference?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The rank formula needs the following variables: number, ref, and [order]

Does the ref have to be continuous?

Example: My ref is in cells A1-C1, however I have another number in another workbook that I want to add to that ref. I have a formula right now.

Here's the background:
We test for various chemicals and depending on the ppm value we take no action, note but no action, minor action, and major action.

Example:
 - less than 3ppm then no action
 - less than 6 but more than 3 no action but take notes
 - less than 10 but more than 6 is minor action etc.

I need to know where my value lies in these tiers. The values in the tiers vary from .0001 to 100000.

Formulas are preferred, VBA will work too but no one else knows VBA so I think a formula will be easier for them and me to troubleshoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to Rank records which are not in single sheet. 
Through this example I would like to show how to achieve it. Suppose you have 3 worksheet. First you need to Name them like, 
={"Class1!$E$2:$E$5","Class2!$B$2:$B$5","Class3!$B$8:$B$11"} 
and then after use this formula, 
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(Score),E2))=0,"N/A",SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(Score),">"&E2))+1).

NB : Score is the name given to the Data Ranges above.

Comment: i'm having a heck of a time here.  
So i used this formula
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(SCORE),C7))=0,"N/A",SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(SCORE),C7))+1)
and here's my named range.
={"Table!$F$7:$H$7","'Test '!$C$7"}
Test'!C7 being both my input and the extra cell i want to include in my reference.   
No matter what my input is i get 2 as a result

Comment: Here's my work around
{=IF(A7="NO","",IF(C7<MIN(OFFSET(INDIRECT(LEFT(D7,2)),MATCH(‌​B7,Table!$B:$B,0)-1,‌​0,1,3)),0,IF(C7>MAX(‌​OFFSET(INDIRECT(LEFT‌​(D7,2)),MATCH(B7,Tab‌​le!$B:$B,0)-1,0,1,3)‌​),4,INDEX(Table!$F$1‌​:$H$1,MATCH(FALSE,OF‌​FSET(INDIRECT(LEFT(D‌​7,2)),MATCH(B7,Table‌​!$B:$B,0)-1,0,1,3)<C‌​7,0)-1))))}

Comment: As you can see its a damn monster. the indirect points to a different table depending on UOM (ppmv vs mg/m3). first i find out if it's less than the min or greater than the max and assigned values 0 to min and 4 to max. if not then i used your formula but replaced the header with 1,2 and 3. This way depending on my input i get a value from 0 to 4 from which then i can program the rest of the logic. Thanks again sir, your formula was the missing link.

Comment: Yes my SUMPRODUCT formula is working only for 1st Range. Im sure soon I will be able to fix it.

Comment: Hey Santa now I've got the solution,, while creating Name Range SCORE you need to hold the Ctrl key to select data ranges. 

Your Range value & Formula will remain same 
Like,, 
={"Class1!$E$2:$E$5","Class2!$B$2:$B$5","Class3!$B$8:$B$11"} 
and then after use this formula,
 =IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(Score),E2))=0,"N/A",SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(Score),">"&E2))+1)
I've tested its working, either you can copy paste all 3 data ranges in Column or let them at their original places, Range will be calculated as combine range.

Comment: Additionally you just copy paste all 3 data ranges in any one column and write this formula will produce same Rank, 

=Rank. EQ(J122, SCORE) & drag it down.